# How to apply arguments to all neural network objects in cell array

Tags: matlab, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, cell-array, generalization

I want to have N parallel neural networks working side by side with the same input parameters. So I decided first to start with 2 neural networks to generalize to N next round.

To do this I created a function called `getUntrainedNet` as follows:

```
function [net] = getUntrainedNet()
%GETUNTRAINEDNET Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

% Choose a Training Function
% For a list of all training functions type: help nntrain
% 'trainlm' is usually fastest.
% 'trainbr' takes longer but may be better for challenging problems.
% 'trainscg' uses less memory. Suitable in low memory situations.
trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt backpropagation.

% Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 30;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize,trainFcn);
end
```

Next I created a cell array `nets` of neural network objects:

```
nets = cell(1,lengthTargets);
nets(:) = {getUntrainedNet()};
```

where `lengthTargets` comes from:

```
Targets = [experiments.TargetOne; experiments.TargetTwo];
lengthTargets = size(Targets,1);
```

Then neural networks are trained with:

```
nets{k} = trainNet(nets{k}, experimentCoordinates, Targets(k,:));
```

To detect the best operating point with a multi objective optimization method called `gamultiobj`, I use the following cost function:

```
costFunction = @(varargin) [nets{1}(varargin{:}'), nets{2}(varargin{:}')];
```

But Instead, I would like to apply `varargin{:}'` parameters to all the neural network objects present in the cell array without having to specify each network by its indexer to make the computation generic.

1) How to do this here?

Once I have the best coordinates I want to apply the parameter of the best coordinates to each neural network object in the cell array.

This is currently being done by:

```
bestCoordinatesTargetOne = nets{1}(bestCoordinates);
bestCoordinatesTargetTwo = nets{2}(bestCoordinates);
```

2) How to do this here without indexing each cell to make the computation generic?

Comment: Use `cellfun` to do the same thing to each element in a cell, in your case these elements are NNs and the thing you want to do is call them with some arguments...

Comment: Thank you @Wolfie,  I just structured your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Wolfie's comment I updated the cost function to:

```
costFunction = @(varargin) cell2mat(cellfun(@(net) net(varargin{:}'), nets, 'UniformOutput',false));
```

And the optimization went through.

And to calculate best coordinates targets:

```
bestCoordinatesTargets = cellfun(@(net) net(bestCoordinates), nets, 'UniformOutput',false);
```